# Mobile CSS Page width

Tags: html, css, mobile, mobile-website

Trying pretty hard to make simple form page viewable in mobile devices. The form is viewable, just that I have to zoom in a lot to read it.

Hear is an example:

http://200.5.3.20/temp/PocketPC/dispatch.php

Answer (score 41):

You can add the meta viewport tag that will scale the page to the device width:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

You can read up on it [here too](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag).

Comment: Excellent! Just used this and instantly my page looks so much better on my iPhone :D Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Apart what jonezy used, `meta viewport tag` as below will also work:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

It will not be scalable and fit to device width - for any device, iOS or Android.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Use mobile doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
```

Comment: WAP? We have CSS3 and HTML5 and you're suggesting WAP?

Comment: This isn't WAP.  It's a standard mobile dtd.  ESPN uses it, for example.

Comment: even facebook uses it. m.facebook.com